# Modelamiento de una tabla

Tags: base-de-datos, mysqli, mariadb

Buen día comunidad, necesito de su ayuda con respecto a la creación de las tablas de una base de datos. El diseño es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La inquietud es solo con respecto a las dimensiones del producto. Como pueden observar en Dimensiones hay 3 registros pero cada uno de ellos tiene su descripción. Por un lado las dimensiones: largo, ancho y profundidad que irían en una tabla para poder agregar más a futuro. La cantidad para ser registrada solo cuando es creado un nuevo producto y la unidad de medida las cuales pueden cambiar, por ejemplo para largo podría ser cm,mm o m. Ahora no se si estas unidades deben ir en una tabla por separado o como podría hacer para que en una sola consulta se pueda ingresar todos estos datos.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. No termino de ver cual es tu duda, ¿que no te sale? Añade lo que has intentado para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte mejor. Un saludo :)

Comment: si las dimensiones siempre son largo, ancho , profundidad.  crearia 6 campos nuevos, largo. ancho . profundidad, mediada_largo , medida_ancho, medida_profundidad. al crear la base de datos puedes indicar que campos son obligatorios y cuales no por lo que podrás rellenarlos mas tarde. si por casualidad no todos productos tuvieran dimensiones si no que las dimensiones pudieran variar y ser solo largo y ancho, o yo que se que se midieran en kilos... crearía dos tablas nuevas donde relacionar esto. una que solo fuera Id y medida, y la otra que fuera id, id_producto, id_medida, unidad, valor.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, si te entendí bien quedaría mas o menos de la siguiente manera: TablaA Producto(id_idproducto,imagen), TablaB Dimensiones(id,dimension) , TablaC Detalle(id,idproducto,id_dimension,cantidad). Pero la única tabla con información sería la TablaB porque cuando vaya a crear el producto quiero que cargue estas  dimensiones(largo, ancho, profundidad) , elegir la medida (cm,mm, kg) y la cantidad para cada dimensión, todo esto en una sola consulta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te comenta Alberto, tienes básicamente 2 opciones.

### Opción 1

Los atributos de dimensión (incluso el de peso y alguno más que se ocurra) siempre van a ser los mismos (salvo en productos digitales, que también podría ser). Entonces podrias ponerlos en la misma tabla que los productos.

Te quedaría algo así como en este [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09b1ed/1)

Yo no me complicaría definiendo unidades, y lo consideraría todo como una unidad estándar, por ejemplo cm (o milímetros si prefieres). A la hora de utilizar la información, por ejemplo en un frontend web o una aplicación de escritorio, puedes hacer las conversiones convenientes.

### Opción 2

Es algo más complicada y puede parecer más profesional, pero a veces va a ser excesivo según las necesidades que tengas. Es poner datos como las medidas en una tabla a parte, con una clave foránea que relaciona cada dato con el producto a quien pertenece.

Lo puedes ver mejor en este [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2120e)

En esta segunda opción, las cosas se complican un poco, y conseguir los datos te va a costar más (no lo hago para que lo hagas/investigues tú) pero si te fijas, en el segundo producto he incorporado su peso en gramos.

Comment: Si la opción 2 es exactamente lo que busco y ya estoy entendiendo como es la estructura, yo se que es un poco mas complicado pero creo que se ajusta más a las necesidades que se tendría a futuro. Y bueno conseguir los datos como recién estoy aprendiendo creo que se me complicaría un poco pero creo que se sería una sentencia que una ambas tablas de lo que estuve revisado. Igualmente muchas gracias por tu ayuda me fue muy útil

Comment: Solo una pregunta más, se puede crear el producto y sus atributos en una sola sentencia sql ? o se debe primero crear el producto y luego añadir sus atributos. Gracias

Comment: Depende de como generes el id de producto que es un valor que deberás insertar en ambas tablas. Si lo generas tu desde el código, ya conoces su valor y puedes hacer dos INSERTS en dos tablas a la vez, si ese id se genera en BBDD tienes que hacer un INSERT en productos, conocer que id le ha asignado, y luego hacer el INSERT en atributos. Se podria hacer (el primer caso también) con el uso de procedimientos almacenados, y parecería como una única sentencia SQL.

Answer (score -1):

Me gusta la opción 2 de Marc, yo añadiría una tabla de atributos para tener controlados los atributos que puedan añadirse a un registro.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Me temo que tu respuesta encaja mas en un comentario que una respuesta ya que no aporta mucho. Si crees que puedes mejorar la respuesta de Marc seria una oportunidad perfecta para no dudes en intentarlo, un saludo :)